# Wishlist for Stack Exchange Question Filtering

Tags: discussion, filtering, custom-questions-list

I am bit puzzled about the limited filtering options provided on SO. Below are some of the filters I wish were available for questions/answers -

- Mark questions/answers as seen and filter out for the seen/unseen category
- Mark question/answers with a *don't show again* type flag
- Filter questions/answers based on user reputation points
- Filter questions/answers based on time period (show last week or date range)
  and many more.

Do these filter types already exist and probably I am not able to find them?

If not, I would like to understand: What are the best practices fellow SOers use to filter out questions/answers?

Comment: You can already ignore/hide tags, perform searches that excludes tags, and search posts with date/year ranges. If you need a UI to help with advanced search, I have [a userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/7971).

Comment: What do you mean by "filtering"? When you search, when you view a specific list, when you make a custom filter?

Comment: I feel the existing search filters are not enough. You really need to read and scroll many questions before finding a relevant question. Specially - filtering out questions based on user reputation or question quality (If we can categorize somehow).

Answer (score -3):

I believe the best option would be to integrate somehow with the SEDE.

Yes I understand that having a SEDE-like functionality to the realtime database might give us more privilege as the company would want to; however this problem could be easily solved by narrowing down the available data to specific tables.

Comment: I don't think it's privileges that are the main problem. It's performance. There's a reason data in SEDE can be up to a week old. It's a completely different database. I've worked on systems where users have been given ad-hoc query access to live databases. I've also gotten the calls asking me to cancel queries because a user caused a deadlock on all of the key tables with a misplaced CROSS JOIN. There are mitigation techniques, but yeah, probably a good idea to avoid SQL-level queries against live databases.

Comment: @HereticMonkey 1. Obviously prod should be replicated to a sede clone, and searches should run on that. 2. Locking becomes no-problem if everybody has only read access. Any number of read lock can exist on the same entity, they are incompatible only with the write locks (and also the write locks are incompatible to each other).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Extension: also this is why the SEDE does not lock, independently with the complexity of the queries running on it. However, during their sync time (about 03:00-05:00 UTC, as I can remember), yes there are often "surprises". Obviously a continuous replication would avoid even this problem (what would be very useful on the current SEDE, too).